# Angular - *ngIf on my buttons doesn't work on boolean changing value dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscription, angular-ng-if

I'll try to make it short. I assign a value (`true` or `false`) to a `boolean` depending of the size of my component.

html (I have two buttons with *ngIf) :

```html
<section #carouselElement>
  <button  *ngIf="showArrows">
        <mat-icon>arrow_back_ios</mat-icon>
   </button>
</section>
```

in my component.ts :

```js
showArrows: boolean;

resizeSubscription$: Subscription;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    // DOM element that contains my buttons
    this.carouselElement = this.explorationCarousel.nativeElement;

    // I console.logged the value and it changes to false or true depending of the
    // the size of the screen
    this.resizeSubscription$ = fromResize(this.carouselElement).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.showArrows = this.canShowArrows();
      }
    );
  }
```

Even though my boolean value changes to the right value thanks to the subscription, why do my *ngIf does not work when when the boolean is false ? When it's false I have to click on the button and then it disappears.

Should I make my boolean an `Observer<boolean>` and my ngIf like this ? `*ngIf="showArrows | async"`

If yes how can I do that please ? I'm a little lost

I tried using Observer type but I got really lost when trying to apply what I saw with the code I have now

I made a exemple of my problem here, you can see in the console that the ngIf does not always work according to the boolean:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k4zrbk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Try rendering the boolean above the ngIf and see if it changes value.

Comment: Could not reproduce your problem. I just copy pasted your code and defined the methods you did not post and I have a working example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kcgmxm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @MehyarSawas
I made a exemple of my problem here, you can see in the console that the ngIf does not always work according to the boolean: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k4zrbk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Jeppe
If it helps I made a exemple of my problem here. The value changes well you can see in the console that the ngIf does not always work according to the boolean: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k4zrbk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Either inject `private zone: NgZone` in constructor and run your code inside `this.zone.run(() => { ... });`. Otherwise inject `private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef` and call `this.cdr.detectChanges();` - since this code is managed by a library and probably "outside" of angular's change-detection, you can make sure they are updated with these 2 methods.

Comment: @Jeppe
I'll check your link
by running my code in `this.zone.run(() => { ... });` you mean what part of the code should I put inside ?

Comment: The code that you want Angular to "detect changes on", e.g. updating the bool value. Angular will then know to update the view(s) etc.

Comment: @Jeppe THANK YOU SO MUCH! 
`this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` did je job for me. (It was the easier to understand so I tried it instead of ngZone) Thank you for your answer